# Manifest merger failed (Using Room)

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

Trying to implement Room in Gradle.

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Not able to build gradle, showing this error

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
```

**sdk version**

```
 compileSdkVersion 22
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "x.x.x"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your android studio version.

```
def roomVersion = "1.1.1"


implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
  kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using multiple versions of the Android Support Libraries, for this, you can try two steps:

1) Put this snippet at the end of your app module build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}
```

}

2) Use the same version of Android Support Library for each component that you want to use.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

3) Change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to the same version (I will use 25 for this example):

```
compileSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: Tried this code also, not working. Dont have to update my sdk version, As working on some big project other things are working on that version.

Comment: Did you include the snippet at the end of your app module in build.gradle?

Check if you've included the "}" that it's out of the format indentation.

Comment: Ok, let's go for the next procedures. What is the buildToolsVersion present on your project?